# How can a PresentingViewController get notified that its PresentedViewController dismissed itself?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, coordinator-pattern

**Given:**

- ViewController A that presents ViewController B
- ViewController B has **no reference** to ViewController A (except implicitly the `presentingViewController` property)
- ViewController B calls `dismiss` on itself and does nothing else

**What I want to achieve:**

- ViewController A wants to know when ViewController B got dismissed in order to clean up some state

**Restrictions:**

- I do not want to use KVO
- I do not want to modify ViewController B or its behavior in any way

**What I have found out so far:**

- `dismiss(animated:completion:)` [according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) forwards the call to its `presentingViewController`. But as it seems `dismiss(animated:completion:)` is **not** called, but rather a private method `_performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:`.
- iOS [documentation on `presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) is misleading. It says "the view controller that was presented has this property set to the view controller that presented it", but that's not true. In iOS 11, this will always point to the root parent VC of the VC that `present` was called on. Similarly the [documentation on `presentedViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621407-presentedviewcontroller) is misleading. It says "the view controller that called the method has this property set to the view controller that it presented", that's not the whole story. Every VC in the hierarchy of the VC (all its parent VCs and child VCs) that called `present` will point to the same `presentedViewController`.

Comment: Maybe sending a notification in `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`  of ViewController B?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify B. I could wrap it in a containerVC as I described in the answer below, but not very nice either

Comment: Or subclass it?

Comment: True, that would also be possible

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller A , kame it as `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and with `navigationController:didShowViewController` mark the presentation of Controller B (`isControllerBisPresented = true`). When `viewDidAppear` of B , check if `isControllerBisPresented` is true.

Comment: Neither ViewController A nor B is a UINavigationController, so unfortunately this does not help much

Comment: Do you have TabViewController , Could you explain your architecture a bit

Comment: Both ViewController A and B are plain UIViewController subclasses. I cannot modify B. A presented B with a call to `present`.

Comment: Maintain a flag in AppDelegate and check that in viewDid methods . Its little manual though

Comment: Yeah pretty manual :-/ Also not very composable if I present something that was itself presented

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround would be to use a man-in-the-middle which does something in `deinit`. So `A` presents `M` which embeds `B` as a childVC. When `B` dismisses itself, `M` will be dismissed implicitly as well, so it's `deinit` method *should* be called. There it can notify `A` that it was dismissed.

This is fragile, as some reference cycle could prevent `M` from being deallocated which would result in `A` not getting notified. So I'd rather want to find a better solution.